# Getting forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: django, apache, django-deployment

i'm trying to deploy django application using apache & mod_wsgi on centos 7.

I have added the following lines in the `httpd.conf` file:

```
Alias /robots.txt /home/centos/sunlife/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /home/centos/sunlife/static/favicon.ico

#Alias /media/ /path/to/mysite.com/media/
Alias /static/ /home/centos/sunlife/static/

<Directory /home/centos/sunlife/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/media>
#Require all granted
#</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/centos/sunlife/sunlife/wsgi.py

<Directory /home/centos/sunlife/sunlife>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

While trying to access the ip, I am getting Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.